# How does Individual Origins calculate the centerpoint on adjacent faces or edges?

Tags: modeling

The [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.4/editors/3dview/controls/pivot_point/individual_origins.html#in-edit-mode) says:

> Each selected element is transformed around its own centerpoint.

Straightforward enough. Each element (vertex, edge, or face, depending on the current select mode) is transformed around the point on its center. An edge's centerpoint is found on the middle of it, and a face's on the center of it.

> When you transform adjacent faces or edges, they are treated as a single element (meaning they don’t become disconnected).

I tested if this was true with an edge of three vertices on `(0,0)`, `(1.5,0)`, and `(2,0)` (Assume Z axis 0). The pivot point should be on `(1,0)` when I transform it (e.g. with scale), but it was somewhere between `(1.2,0)` and `(1.3,0)`.

Comment: Interesting... For edges and vertices it doesn't seem to be median point...

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys It is, but just as lemon shows in his answer, it is not the median point of the bounding box. And it is the same for faces, too. If you have a simple plane with 4 vertices and set the origin point, then _Origin to Center of Mass (Surface)_ and _Origin to Center of Mass (Volume)_ will give the same result: the visual center of the plane. However, if you make loopcuts off the center, then those two methods will show different results: the _Origin to Center of Mass (Volume)_ is no longer in the visual center of the overall plane, it's shifted towards the higher amount of vertices.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys But when you take a cube instead, _Origin to Center of Mass (Surface)_ and _Origin to Center of Mass (Volume)_ again will be the same, no matter if you have off-centered loopcuts leading to an uneven distributed contentration of vertices. But now the option _Origin to Geometry_ will put the origin off the center. By the way, the function Ctrl+S > _Cursor to Selected_ also takes the distribution of vertices into account and places the cursor off the visual median point of the overall selection.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann, not exactly. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/291874/19156

Comment: I struggle with English names for math concepts a bit and with math in general :D , but it seems you get the centers if you average the coordinates of centers of connected edges or faces and median point of that connected geometry is calculated differently. Lemon's answer seems to be the correct answer.

Comment: @lemon Not exactly what? I took a simple square plane as example, there the _Origin to Center of Mass (Surface)_ is independent of how the individual faces / vertices are distributed if you cut it up as you can see in this example of a randomly cut plane: [different origins](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uv01vXHz_JeIJOClSWorM8wplSd4PnuV/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann, I thought you wrote center of mass (surface) and center of mass (volume) were the same.

Comment: @lemon Well, I did - but only for a simple plane with only 4 vertices ;)

Comment: I don't' know what you guys are talking about, but what I meant is that I did for some reason expect the center of connected geometry to match whatever center it has when the same geometry is selected and Median Point is chosen for Transform Pivot Point, that's all.

Comment: [I tested it](https://i.imgur.com/jPGOZL6.gif)

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys When you have only one connected mesh, there is no difference between median and individual, because individual also scales on median points - but for separate mesh islands. If you had two separate edge islands, there would be a difference between median and individual pivot point. But  that has nothing to do with the question. The OP was wondering why a straight edge with 3 vertices going from 0 to 2 on X does not rotate around the seemingly obvious median point at X = (2-0)/2 = 1, and this is explained by lemon's answer - because the vertices are unevenly distributed.

Comment: Have a look at my gif. Median of the same connected geometry scales to different pivot point that if individual is set. It scales to location different than  3d Cursor is set with Median pivot point and then to exactly 3d cursor with individual.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys The difference you are seeing in your gif is that _Median Point_ uses the center of all vertices, regardless of the edge connections. _Individual Origins_ takes the centers of each individual edge and calculates the median point from them. Which means, if you would connect the first and last vertex of your path, both pivot point methods would again scale from the same median point. If you then add more connecting edges between different points, the pivot point methods might again differ from each other, depending on where those edges are. But that's explained in lemon's answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145888/discussion-between-gordon-brinkmann-and-martynas-ziemys).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When individual origins, I presume we cannot scale or rotate vertices individually, so the minimum individual elements are edges.

If we take your example, the first segment center is:

```
1.5 / 2 => 0.75
```

and the second is

```
1.5 + (0.5 / 2) => 1.75
```

so the mean is

```
(0.75 + 1.75) / 2 => 1.25
```

Another way to see it could be:

- take all individual elements centers
- make island defining their center as the mean of the island elements centers
- scale or rotate around that center